# Timer when multiple instances are running ( eg cloud )

Tags: timer, redis, cloud

Problem: Creating a timer through application will have duplicate the timers when multiple application instances are running.

Problem area: create a timer on cloud.

Can redis be used as timer on cloud? For example, write a record to redis and set ttl(time to live). Once TTL is reached, redis messaging system can be used to receive notification( thereby, executing the task).

The problem is redis seem to be having only publish subscribe mechanism. That means all app instances receive the notification, duplicating the task.

Any suggestions?

Comment: first try something and then ask question

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue a while ago. There are different strategies.

- You cloud provider may already have a solution.
- Create some sort of Control Database. And lock/check using this db whether the timer is already running for particular instance or tenant.
- Send messages to messaging system and make sure duplicates removed.
- Run timer process inside lightweight container. Some sort of microservice.
- Use any third parties to achieve these.
- etc

Every solution has its own pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks tanzwud, But how did you solve in your scenario?

Comment: I'm not able to go deep into details. Microsoft Azure as cloud provider have a solution for us. We used it.